# How can I create text-based aliases? (Local hyperlinks?)

Tags: macos, ms-office, textedit, alias

I need to use deeply-buried files/folders on a hard disk at work. I can create aliases, which is helpful. An alias gives me an icon that I can double-click to open the original. But I would like to create clickable text "hyperlinks" to use in things like Excel spreadsheets, TextEdit, to do lists, etc.

Clicking one of those links would open the corresponding file/folder in Finder. It would function essentially as an html hyperlink, only referencing a local file. That would let me set up my workflow in advance with all the links in place for each project.

Use case:

> TODO:
>   • Read the [Quarterly Report](http://www.example.com)
>   • Review new applicants in the [Product Manager Applicant Folder](http://www.example.com)

I have researched automator and aliases but haven't found anything to create text-based aliases. I appreciate any help.

Comment: How about creating template files? Then you can use the alias feature to open the template file and use  a "Save as..." feature on the application to create a new file based on the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this without 3rd-party software.

However, you can definitely do this with [OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus/).

You can "attach" files, but have that attachment simply be a "link" to the file, so it's not actually moved inside your OmniFocus database, it still exists on your filesystem.

Then your reminder/to-do could be something like "Review Quarterly Report" and have that report attached as an OmniFocus link.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer. I don't have enough reputation yet to show you that I voted you up, but I did. I've actually spent the last month digging into OmniFocus. It seems like that is the solution to my problem. I can now create task lists and link files and folders from anywhere the internal structure of my hard drive. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for letting me know. I’m glad to hear it’s working for you. I’ve used OmniFocus for years and think it’s a great app. Lots of power, lots of features, so it can seem daunting / complex, but it’s worth the effort, IMO. Also, welcome to SE!